# Why do we only review late answers when they're posted by new users?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, answers

Why not any late answer? I would hope that late answers provided by established users have a high chance of being new revelations on an old/previously unanswerable problem and therefore interesting to a wide audience.

Could the Late Answers queue be used to get some attention for this kind of answer?

Comment: That's not the goal of reviewing late answers. The goal is to detect spam and other posts that are *not* answers.

Comment: The question will already go to the top of the "active" list when a new answer is entered.

Comment: If the queue is just to remove spam/non-answers, why is "Vote up" a valid review action?

Comment: @RobEarl: Sometimes such a new post *happens to be great*, so why preclude you from upvoting such posts? We also want to encourage new users participating, provided they do it right.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? It's a standard review option.

Comment: There are plans being kicked around to rework some of this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236537/lets-have-an-explicit-triage-system-for-questions-from-new-users

Comment: 10K+ users have access to a full feed of all late answers to old (30 days or more) questions.

Answer (score 10):

Late answers by new users is a typical *pattern* which has been identified over time to have an extremely high likelihood of being spam or non-answers. A lot of users find questions on SO via Google, and some who do not understand what SO is or how it works feel inclined to post "Thank you" notes or follow up questions as answers. This has become so typical that SO created a special review queue only for that case.

Answer (score 8):

The goal of the Late Answer review queue is to catch posts that are not answers. It is *not* a goal of the queue to bring interesting posts to your attention.

New users are more likely to post things that are [not actual answers to the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-it-is-not-an-answer), such as *did you solve this yet?* or outright spam.

Such posts might otherwise not receive enough attention to get these cleaned up, which is why we ask reviewers to look such posts over in a dedicated queue.

If you are interested in new answers, *full stop*, look at the *Active* tab of a tag, as new answers will bump up questions onto that tab.